# Why is php7.4-curl version not installed?

Tags: apt, server, php, curl, php7

I me an Ubuntu 22.04 cloud server. Site version php 7.4.30

**I needed to install curl version 7.4, I did the following:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install php7.4-curl
```

As a result, it installs version 7.8.1, which works only with php 8

Please help with this problem. What do I need to do for this?

Answer (score 1):

It's installed. You are confusing versions of `php-curl` with the version of `curl` for which `php-curl` is a binding library.

I've just created a fresh LXC container for Jammy, updated it, added the `ppa:ondrej` repository updated it further, and installed that package. After that, I listed the files installed by the package and I see no signs that it has installed `php7.8.1-culr`. However `curl` (which is not a PHP library, is on version 7.8.1 by default on Ubuntu Jammy), but the installed PHP library will successfully work with that version of `curl`. I successfully tested by installing `php7.4-cli` and using the example code at: [php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php](https://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)